# AMD dedicated card not detected?

Tags: amd-graphics

I have the problem with my R6 dedicated card. I can't see the R6 graphics card in lspci -v . and also when i see 'about this computer', it only detected my R5 integrated vga card. Actually i have catalyst control center and i've set both plugged in mode and unplugged in mode power in "high performance". But, i'm not sure if it detected my R6 as well. What should i do?

AMD Carrizo 8700P ( R5 + R6 2 gb VRAM )

Comment: Please also post the model of your notebook. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot
ASUS X555DG